# When are two answers too similar?

Tags: support

[Is it true that $0.999999999\ldots = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11)  [math fallacy problem: $-1= (-1)^3 = (-1)^{6/2} = \sqrt{(-1)^6}= 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472227) [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49169) have many similar answers. When is this sanctioned?

Because I like figures, I wrote https://math.stackexchange.com/a/676192/85079 by dint of another answer. I referred to it. I think this similar but not identical answer can aid other people. But a moderator deleted it. The changes can aid other people, ergo can we have both? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 18):

It is fine and unavoidable that wo people give structurally similar answers by accident. But that doesn't mean that copy-pasting someone elses answer and changing a few sysmbols is acceptable behavior.

Answer (score 18):

It's fine (and perhaps unavoidable) that $2$ users submit structurally similar answers by happenstance. But this does not imply that copy-pasting someone else's answer and changing a few symbols should be tolerated.

Comment: http://cdn.avsforum.com/0/04/04be3904_18462291.jpeg

Comment: @Asaf: Demystify wherefore this vatic effigy emanates feyly.

Comment: Are you going to start using colors now, too? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: $\textbf{colo}\color{red}{\textbf{u}}\textbf{rs}$.

Comment: I know that Canadian are educated folks who understand the metric system. But I didn't know that they go to the theatre and like to sit at the centre while their favourite movie plays.

Comment: The irony on this post is too high. :p No offence. This is just amusing.